# Clustered MSMQ Issue

Tags: msmq

I am having an issue with MSMQ in a clustered environment. I have the following setup:

2 Nodes setup in a Windows Failover, lets call them "Node A" and "Node B".

I have then setup a Clustered Instance of MSMQ lets call it "MSMQ Instance".

I have also setup a Clustered instance of the DTC, lets call it "DTC Instance".

Within the DTC  instance, I have allowed access both locally and also through the Clustered instance, basically I have taken all authentication off to test.

I have also created a clustered instance of our In house application, lets call it "Application Instance". Within this Application instance, I have other resources added, which are other services the application uses and also the Net.MSMQ adapter.

The Issue.......

When I seem to Cluster the Application Instance, it always seems to set the owner to be the opposite Node that I am using, so if I am creating the Clustered Instance on Node A it always sets the current owner to Node B, however that is not the issue.

The issue I have is that as long as the Application Instance is running on Node B, MSMQ seems to work.

The outbound queues are created locally, receive messages and are then processed through the MSMQ Cluster.

If I then Failover to Node A, the MSMQ refuses to work. The outbound queues are not created and therefore no messages are being processed.

I get an error in Event Viewer:

"The version check failed with the error: 'Unrecognized error -1072824309 (0xc00e000b)'. The version of MSMQ cannot be detected All operations that are on the queued channel will fail. Ensure that MSMQ is installed and is available"

If I then failover back to Node B it works.

The Application has been setup to use the MSMQ instance and all the permissions are correct.

Do I need to have a Clustered instance of DTC or can I just configure it as resource within the MSMQ instance?

Can anybody shed any light on this as I am at a brick wall with this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to have a clustered DTC setup.

For your clustered MSMQ instance you will then need to configure the clustered DTC as a "`dependendy`" Right click on `MSMQ -> Properties -> Dependencies`

I do not know if this is mandatory in all cases, but on our Cluster we also have a file share configured as a dependcy for the MSMQ. To my understanding this should ensure that temporary files that are needed by MSMQ are still available after a node switch.

Additionally, here are two articles that I found very helpful in setting up the cluster nodes. They might be helpful in confirming step-by-step that your configurations are correct:

- "[Building MSMQ cluster](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mismail/archive/2007/04/18/building-an-msmq-cluster.aspx)". You will find several other links in that article that will guide you further.
- Microsoft also has a detailed document: "[Deploying Message Queuing (MSMQ) 3.0 in a Server Cluster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=349D6584-9510-46F5-904E-2C58FA16EB85&displaylang=en&displaylang=en)".